# Hibernate: can fetch collection eagerly, but not lazily

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

From my previous question [Hibernate: can save the object, but cannot load it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046514/hibernate-can-save-the-object-but-cannot-load-it-back), I had the model class (entity) as this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "UserDetails")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    private Collection<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now the collection `addresses` has annotation `@ElementCollection` from `jpa` which uses this information to create another table with each for for each element in that collection. Now the way the hibernate fetches these element back has 2 different ways: `fetch = FetchType.EAGER | FetchType.LAZY`. The lazy way, is the default one. Now when I (as in my previous question) didn't specify the fetch type (which defaults to LAZY way), I got

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
```

Application context error (which doesn't help to diagnose the issue, btw). However after changing the fetch type to EAGER, no error happened. So the question is why (why cannot the hibernate handle the default-lazy way) ?

Comment: `To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.` <- It seems like your application is telling you how you would get a more meaningfull error message. Have you tried running it with debug enabled?

Comment: I do. as `mvn spring-boot:run --debug` but that gives some garbage about running maven phases, not actuall error caused by application context

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS still, that doesn't asnwer the reason why `eager way` can and `lazy way` cannot

Comment: You need to try/catch and then log the exceptions to figure it out and give you/us some context to work with.  What is Address though, seems like it should be a 1:m mapping to an entity, not an element collection.